# Reset/Allow addEventListener after removeEventListener

Tags: addeventlistener

Still pretty new to Javascript so apologies if this Q has been asked a hundred times, not completely sure what I should be searching for (terminology).

I have a couple nested events and these so far work, and removing these events works as well. The issue is that once the event is removed with `removeEventListener`, the `addEventListener` events no longer fire again without a page reload.

Current code:

```
// Listen for mousedown.  
handle.addEventListener("mousedown", function icHandleDrag (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dragging = true;
  // Listen for mousemove.
  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function icResizeResize (ex) {
    var adjustOffsetLeft = ex.pageX - icContainerLeft,
      offsetLocation = ((adjustOffsetLeft / icContainerWidth) * 100) + "%";
    
    if (adjustOffsetLeft > (icContainerWidth * 0.01) && adjustOffsetLeft < (icContainerWidth * 0.99)) {
      resize.style.width = offsetLocation;
      handle.style.left = offsetLocation;
    }
    
    // Listen for mouseup.
    handle.addEventListener("mouseup", function icStopDragging () {
      if (dragging) {
        // Remove event listeners.
        handle.removeEventListener("mousedown", icHandleDrag);
        document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", icResizeResize);
        handle.removeEventListener("mouseup", icStopDragging);
        dragging = false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In most docs/posts I've read, the suggestions say to create a function, then pass that function to a separate event listener (not quite sure how to do that with the current nested structure).

**Is there a way I can keep my `addEventListener`'s functioning after a `removeEventListener`? Or will I have to look at a different approach for structurinng this code?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are removing the `mousedown` EventListener and it never gets added again.

I've changed the code you provided. Now the `mousedown` is not being removed, and have isolated the functions for readability.

See if this helps.

```
// Listen for mousedown.  
handle.addEventListener("mousedown", icHandleDrag);

function icHandleDrag (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragging = true;

    // Listen for mousemove.
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", icResizeResize);
}

  function icResizeResize (ex) {
    var adjustOffsetLeft = ex.pageX - icContainerLeft,
      offsetLocation = ((adjustOffsetLeft / icContainerWidth) * 100) + "%";
    
    if (adjustOffsetLeft > (icContainerWidth * 0.01) && adjustOffsetLeft < (icContainerWidth * 0.99)) {
      resize.style.width = offsetLocation;
      handle.style.left = offsetLocation;
    }
    
    // Listen for mouseup.
    handle.addEventListener("mouseup", icStopDragging);
  }

  function icStopDragging () {
    if (dragging) {
      // Remove event listeners.
      document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", icResizeResize);
      handle.removeEventListener("mouseup", icStopDragging);
      dragging = false;
    }
  }
```